# Asp.net Core 2.1 NullReferenceException Error in Production but Not Development

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, asp.net-core-2.1

So this one is throwing me for a loop. I have a asp.net core 2.1 app that I have recently moved from development to production. The app works perfectly in development with no issues or errors. When I move the app to the production server I am getting a null reference exception when trying to call any page from the main menu.

[image: Sample Error From Site]

For this page its stating that my error is on line 85. When I look at line 85 in my development code its a simple assignment operator where Form = new Form().
[image: Code Picture]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I can't seem to understand what is going on.

Comment: 1. Using Developer Exception Page in production environment is not recommened. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: don't just go by the line number.. add additional logging in PROD to check if wi gets a valid value, or if wi.Name is null

Comment: 2. Are you sure User.Identity is of type WindowsIdentity? Locally you can have it as WindowsIdentity, but over Internet I guess you have no way to get WindowsIdentity unless user and website are on the same network.

Comment: I know its not recommended but I always have it on while doing the initial install on production so that I can see the errors if they occur more easily. I take it out after I am sure the app is running correctly.

Comment: 3. Remote debugging session is something you cannot use?

Comment: Maybe to clarify a little better the app is going to be used on the intranet only. Its not going to be accessible outside of our network.

Comment: @dropoutcoder what do you mean by remote debugging session?

Comment: You connect Visual Studio to running process on the server and debug it as you do it locally. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Matt.G I think you are on to the issue. I just checked my code and I have that same identity code running on each page right before the error is thrown. I guess the line number was really throwing me off. I'm going to try and look more into it. If I find the answer then I'll post it here.

Comment: @dropoutcoder I'll look into that. Thank you for the link.

Comment: First, always post your code as text. Images make it much more difficult to help you. That said, I count no less than 5 potential places in this short bit of code that could generate `NullReferenceException`. Any time something could potentially be null, you need to defensively code for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks to @dropoutcoder for idea of remote debugging. After I was able to establish the connection and look through the code I found out the error was due to a null return from a database get that I was doing for the employee. I was in fact retrieving an id from the windowsidentity but it was not an id that I had stored in my database which is why I received the null error. I do plan on continuing to use the remote debugging in the future as without it, I probably would not have been able to understand the problem. I have also changed my code to handle the possible null exception that may happen from my code.

Comment: I'd recommend setting up a staging environment that is identical to production so that you don't have to remote debug a live system, should you run into an issue.

Comment: I will see if I can set something up like that. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I am glad you sorted it!